# Is there a way to automatically hide the status bar when the landscape keyboard is open?

Tags: keyboard

For reasons I will not go into, my cellphone has a very small screen. It would really be nice if the landscape virtual keyboard would open in fullscreen, to leave a bit more room for larger keys. Any ideas how to achieve this?

If it makes any difference, I have an old-timey Motorola Droid running CyanogenMod 7.2.0-sholes.